# PCIDSS masking bank account number

Tags: masking, pci-dss, pci-compliance

I am just curious, do PCIDSS regulation requires us to mask the bank account number? i know that credit card numbers need to be masked, but how about bank account number?

Thanks for the answer in advance

Comment: PCI applies specifically to *card* details, non-card bank account details are not part of its purview. That said enacting its principles for any sensitive information is sensible, if you don't need to display the full number, don't display it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 3):

No, even with the latest PCI-DDS 3.0 you don't **have** to mask bank account numbers to be PCI compliant.

All they care about is Cardholder Data, in particular - PAN (Card Number). PAN **must** be stored encrypted (strong encryption, like AES-128 + KEKs and Keys Management) and masked everywhere it's displayed.

Anything else - including cards expire dates, addresses, bank routing and account numbers - literally, everything besides PANs (excluding CVC code and magnetic strip data [which you **can not** store under any circumstances]) - you can store in open form, and even display it everywhere and still be PCI compliant.

On the other hand, there's common sense. For security you **should** encrypt and mask the bank account numbers as well. They can be compromised too, and it won't bring you any good times.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for the info. I have a query that is mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60861287/information-security-encryption-decryption-key-management-pcidss-padss-com. How would we manage the encryption key ?